# How to exclude all the files from configuration folders in ShadowJar

Tags: gradle, shadowjar

I would like to exclude all **configuration xml** files from **/conf** folder. However, with my shadowJar setting below (see line ***), I still see names.xml (which is a xml file under /conf) is included in the jar.

If I specifically exclude the names.xml file. I wouldn't see it but I will have to put exclude for each file under /conf folder.

Is there a way I can use something like exclude "conf/*.xml" to achieve this?

My project structure is like below:

```
myproject
   - conf
   - src
        -java
        -spring
```

and my shadowJar definition is:

```
 shadowJar {

    version = '0.0.1'
    mergeServiceFiles()
    append("META-INF/spring.schemas")
    append("META-INF/spring.handlers")
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "com.common.server.Main.java"
    }
    exclude "names.xml"  //this is working.
    exclude "conf/*"     //***this is not working
}
```

I am a newbie to shadowJar and I tried several ways to exclude files under a folder with no luck, could someone please give me a hint?

Comment: There is something wrong, why does shadowJar includes "conf" to begin with? By default it operates on source sets only. Is "conf" marked as a module or being included somewhere in your script?

Comment: @Alexiy Hi Alexiy, I don't specify conf as the sourceSet however, I feel like conf folder was recognized as configuration folder by default. Because I noticed that if I rename conf as configuration, then it is not included. Very strange. Do you have any thought on that?

Answer (score 3):

```
dependencies {
    exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
    exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
    exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    exclude "**/*.html"
    exclude "module-info.*"
    exclude "Log4j-*"
    exclude "mime.types"
    exclude "VersionInfo.java"
  }
```

Please try in this format.

Comment: For clarification, this works when placed inside shadowJar's 'minimize' block.

Comment: @Col-E can you edit the answer?